# SSRS ..How to create drop down menu for different databases in same server

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Please help me in this....

There are few databases DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4,DB5....

each database has same tables T1,T2,T3.....Tn. (each table has same columns C1, C2, C3......Cn... but data in those tables are different)

Requirement: *query:* select C1, C2, C3 from T1 inner join T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4

the query will be same for all databases.

First step is to create drop down menu for Databases DB1, DB2, DB3, DB4, DB5

Then select one or more databases after that the query should run for selected database or databeses.

What source should I select and how to create dataset for them?

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried already.

Comment: @MechSoftware - its hard to post code for Reporting Services, when he is not sure how to write the sproc (code) to get what he is after.  That is why he is asking.

Comment: @JonH He could take a stab at writing it and show us what he has.

Comment: @MechSoftware writing what? That is exactly his question, `how do I get the databases to load the drop down menu` is what he is after.  If he pulls the data via master..sysdatabases he wants to know what data source to use, thats his question, he cannot provide an answer because he does not know.  Hence his reason for being here and posting a legitimate question.  If he posted a school assignment asking for help we can ask, `please post some code for what you have done` but his question is pretty straightforward - he needs help on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I disagree, I think an attempt at either code or what he believes are the right databases could be attempted.  In either case I don't think we'll see eye to eye on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 .. How to create drop down menu for different databases in same server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185390/ssrs-2008-how-to-create-drop-down-menu-for-different-databases-in-same-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datasource could be ANY of the databases, the master db, or a newly created database called say "DBA".  Then after you have the source you'd create a stored procedure that would fill up your drop down list with database names:

`select name from master..sysdatabases`

A dataset in reporting services is simply either table direct or stored procedure.  In your case, you should make that a stored procedure that pulls the names of all the databases.

A datasource in RS means where you are going to pull the data, in reality this doesnt matter because you can access any data from any database including linked servers.  In the case of another database simply use the database name.owner.table name.